# Converting a SASS If/Else block to its equivalent in Less

Tags: less, linear-gradients

There is a little SASS to LESS convergence here... Does anyone know what is the correct syntax for these? The code below is the pure SASS mixins I used to use. Thanks for helping

```
@mixin linear-gradient($left, $right, $optional:false) {
  @if $optional and type_of($optional) == number {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient($optional + deg, $left, $right);
    background: -o-linear-gradient($optional + deg, $left, $right);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient($optional + deg, $left, $right);
    background: linear-gradient($optional + deg, $left, $right);
  } @else {
    @if $optional == "right" {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, $left, $right);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(left, $left, $right);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, $left, $right);
      background: linear-gradient(to right, $left, $right);
    } @if $optional == "left" {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, $left, $right);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(right, $left, $right);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, $left, $right);
      background: linear-gradient(to left, $left, $right);
    } @else { // top to bottom
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient($right, $left);
      background: -o-linear-gradient($right, $left);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient($right, $left);
      background: linear-gradient($right, $left);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less uses guarded mixins with `when` conditions to mimick the `if/else` logic. You can convert that SASS mixin to its Less equivalent like shown below. Most of the code is self explanatory (provided you have basic understanding of how Less works). I have also added some comments inline to make it clearer.

```
.linear-gradient(@left, @right, @optional:false) {
  & when (isnumber(@optional)) { //just isnumber check should be enough because default value is also not a number
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(~"@{optional}deg", @left, @right);
    /* "@{optional}deg" is used for string concatenation, ~ outputs the value w/o quotes */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(~"@{optional}deg", @left, @right);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(~"@{optional}deg", @left, @right);
    background: linear-gradient(~"@{optional}deg", @left, @right);
  } 
  & when not (isnumber(@optional)) { //else part
    & when (@optional = right) { //if value of optional param is right
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, @left, @right);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(left, @left, @right);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, @left, @right);
      background: linear-gradient(to right, @left, @right);
    } 
    & when (@optional = left) { //else if value of optional param is left
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, @left, @right);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(right, @left, @right);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, @left, @right);
      background: linear-gradient(to left, @left, @right);
    } 
    & when (@optional = false) { // else if the value is the default value
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@right, @left);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(@right, @left);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(@right, @left);
        background: linear-gradient(@right, @left);
    }        
  }
}
```

and invoke it like (ignore the values for first two params, just dummy)

```
div#div1{
    .linear-gradient(10px, 10px, 10);
}
div#div2{
    .linear-gradient(10px, 10px, right);
}
div#div3{
    .linear-gradient(10px, 10px, left);
}
div#div4{
    .linear-gradient(10px, 10px);
}
```

The compiled output would be

```
div#div1 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(10deg, 10px, 10px);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(10deg, 10px, 10px);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(10deg, 10px, 10px);
  background: linear-gradient(10deg, 10px, 10px);
}
div#div2 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, 10px, 10px);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, 10px, 10px);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, 10px, 10px);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, 10px, 10px);
}
div#div3 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, 10px, 10px);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, 10px, 10px);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, 10px, 10px);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, 10px, 10px);
}
div#div4 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(10px, 10px);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(10px, 10px);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(10px, 10px);
  background: linear-gradient(10px, 10px);
}
```

**Note:** As mentioned in comments, it is always better to use the built in `unit` function or the math operation to convert a plain number into degrees (or anything like px, em etc) instead of using the string concatenation method. The following are samples on how to do it.

Using `unit` function:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(unit(@optional,deg), @left, @right);
```

Using math operation:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@optional * 1deg, @left, @right);
```

Comment: `~"@{optional}deg"` - As always it's not a good idea, even if it is absolutely fine in this particular case, in a long run the recirculation of this trick leads to lotsa confusions when it's not working in more complex cases. It's always recommended to use either `unit` or `@optional * 1deg` (even if they are not the same as Sass `$optional + deg` of the original mixin).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Yes, agreed. It is always better to use the built-in functions or the math operation.

Comment: Thank you Harry, you solved my problem :) And based on this one, I was able to convert the rest of my conditional sass mixins to less.

Comment: @CreativeZoller: Welcome mate. Very glad to have been of help :)