# LESS mixin: How to loop through passed in arguments

Tags: less, mixins

I usually write SASS, but for a particular project I have to use LESS.

How do I achieve something like the below using less? Using sass the mixin can be called like @include align(hcenter top) to position an element horizontally in the middle and to the top.

```
@mixin align($styles) {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;

  @each $style in $styles {

      @if ($style == center) {
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
          margin-top: auto;
          margin-bottom: auto;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          top: 0;
          bottom: 0;
      }
      @if ($style == hcenter) {
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
      }
      @if ($style == vcenter) {
          margin-top: auto;
          margin-bottom: auto;
          top: 0;
          bottom: 0;
      }
      @if ($style == top) {
          top: 0;
      }
      @if ($style == bottom) {
          bottom: 0;
      }
      @if ($style == right) {
          right: 0;
      }
      @if ($style == left) {
          left: 0;
      }

    }

}
```

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163660/converting-a-sass-if-else-block-to-its-equivalent-in-less/26164200#26164200

Comment: Previous one is for SASS to Less conversion. Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440789/loop-through-array-of-values-in-less/21441220#21441220) for looping in Less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Mixin Arguments](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-the-arguments-variable), [List Functions](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions) and [Loops](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature).

With a thing like ["for"](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/src/for.less) the snippet can be converted to something like:

```
@import "loops/for";

#usage {
    .align(hcenter, top, bottom, etc);
}

.align(@styles...) {
    position: absolute;
    content:  '';
    display:  block;

    .for(@styles); .-each(@style) {
        & when (@style = center) {
            margin-left:   auto;
            margin-right:  auto;
            margin-top:    auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            left:   0;
            right:  0;
            top:    0;
            bottom: 0;
        }
        & when (@style = hcenter) {
            margin-left:   auto;
            margin-right:  auto;
            left:   0;
            right:  0;
        }
        & when (@style = vcenter) {
            margin-top:    auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            top:    0;
            bottom: 0;
        }
        & when (@style = top) {
            top:    0;
        }
        & when (@style = bottom) {
            bottom: 0;
        }
        & when (@style = right) {
            right:  0;
        }
        & when (@style = left) {
            left:   0;
        }
    }
}
```

## ---

Actually above code can be optimized to more compact:

```
.align(@styles...) {
    position: absolute;
    content:  '';
    display:  block;

    .center(@pos) {
        margin-@{pos}: auto;
        @{pos}: 0;
    }

    .for(@styles);
        .-each(center)  {.-each(hcenter); .-each(vcenter)}
        .-each(hcenter) {.center(left); .center(right)}
        .-each(vcenter) {.center(top); .center(bottom)}
        .-each(@style)  when (default()) {@{style}: 0}
}
```

Though this way it may look more confusing for one not too familiar with Less.

Comment: I like the second version a lot. Though as you rightly said, a beginner will take time to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your each loop. For instance `(center, top;)` will set `top: 0;` twice?
But you can try:

```
.align(@styles){
.setproperties(@iterator:1) when (@iterator <= length(@styles)) {

    @style: extract(@styles,@iterator);

    & when (@style = center) {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    & when (@style = hcenter)
    {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    // add more & when 's here

    .setproperties((@iterator + 1));
}
position: absolute;
content: '';
display: block;
.setproperties();
}
```

The above can be called with:

```
selector1 {
    .align(center;);
}
selector2 {
    .align(center hcenter;);
}
```

Comment: Btw., Bass, I noticed recently you stopped to apply any intends for your Less code. Is there some specific reason for this or it's just some copy-paste problem? (Those are quite hard to read).

Comment: @seven-phases-max, thanks for the feedback. I promise to behave better and pay more attention to it